# Fix $x$ and $y$ in $\Bbb R$. Suppose that $x < y + e$ for all $e>0$. Prove that $x\leqslant y$.

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

I just started learning proofs in analysis class and this is my first time in this page.
I learned about the Completeness Axiom and tried to solve some problems, but none of them look easy to me

This is my proof:

Assume $x>y$ is true, then there exists a number $n$ in natural numbers such that $n>e$ thereby making $x+n>y+e$ by the Archimedean Property
$x+n>y+e$ and $x<y+e$ contradiction
Therefore, $x\leqslant y$

(I think my proof is seriously messy)

If it is possible can you please tell me how can I approach proof problems?
Should I first look at the answers and memorize them all or just keep trying?
I have no idea where to start
And can you also teach me where can I learn how to write a decent coded math equation so that I can clearly deliver my questions?
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: why is there a contradiction in your proof?

Comment: Because I can always set x as y+n such that n>e...?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are not variables. You cannot set them as you like

Comment: Then, should I say that if x>y, there exists e>0 such that x-y>e? :(

Comment: Assume that $x>y$. So you have $0<x-y$ . so $0<\frac{x-y}{2}<x-y$. This means that for $e=\frac{x-y}{2}$ . You have $y+e=\frac{x+y}{2}\leq\frac{x+x}{2}=x $ which contradicts that $x<y+e\,\,,\forall e>0$ . Therefore it must be that $x\leq y$ as it is the negation of the statement $x>y$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $x>y$. So you have $0<x-y$ . so $0<\frac{x-y}{2}<x-y$. This means that for $e=\frac{x-y}{2}$ . You have $y+e=\frac{x+y}{2}\leq\frac{x+x}{2}=x $ which contradicts that $x<y+e\,\,,\forall e>0$ . Therefore it must be that $x\leq y$ as it is the negation of the statement $x>y$ .

It is usually a really bad idea to try and memorize everything. It is better to try and understand the logical flow. Ask yourself at each step that "if this did not hold, then what problem I am running into". Then obviously it comes down to intuition, knowledge and application of basic algebra.

Comment: Wow....awesome...thank you so much I don't know why I cannot think like this when I first look at the problem I will bear your advice in mind

Comment: @slowpoke you can mark as answer(any one  of them) to remove it from unanswered section. Also these things will come to you naturally with more practise and familiarity with real analysis. Give it a few months. Everyone struggles with these intially .

Comment: Thank you so much I will try to spend more time trying the proofs

Comment: Great! . You will find things a bit tedious at first. You will feel like : "Oh , I know this has to be true intuitively, why do we have to justify everything so rigorously??" . But if you keep patient and just keep trying , you will begin to understand why such rigor is necessary and why without these the formulation of mathematics would become even more difficult.  All the best to you. Have fun learning !!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need completeness for this. For example the same statement holds in $\mathbb{Q}$.

By contraposition: suppose $x>y$; then we have
$$
x>y+\frac{x-y}{2}
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Yes, I see. if I set e=(x-y)/2 then the inequality holds which means that x>y is a wrong assumption. So, it must be x=<y. Thank you so much. There are so many kind people in this page :)

Comment: @slowpoke You seem to have a fancy for contradiction. It's not necessary here. The idea is to prove *if $x>y$, then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $x>y+\varepsilon$* (contrapositive of the statement you have to prove). In general, “A implies B” is equivalent to “not B implies not A”.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct proof (just a rewording of the other answers): since by hypothesis, the claim is true for any $\epsilon>0,$ we may consider specifically elements of the set $\{\epsilon_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}=\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb N}.$ Now, suppose $z>y.$ Then, there is an integer $N$ such that $x<y+\frac{1}{N}<z$. We have shown that $x$ is less than any number $z$ which is greater than $y.$ That is, $x\le y.$